# Run multiple sequential command on a single DOS terminal using php

Tags: php

I have a scenario in which I have to run multiple commands one after another in a single DOS window using PHP. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a batch (.bat or .cmd) file and then execute it

Comment: i mean, which part of batch execution is coded with php. the main question is very poor, he/she might want to get the output of the command, or pass parameters to the commands, "make a batch and execute it" looks unclear to me

Comment: ok, u can generate batch script using php, each command can be suffixed with ">>" to redirect an output. then u can save this script to file using php, and then execute it (for example, using exec()). it is also possible to read file or execution results via php. have i answered ur question?